# Move draggable between drop-down lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I am making a navigation menu editing interface and I have a simple multy-level menu with mouse over expanding sub-menus.

```
<nav>
    <ul class="sortable1 connectedSortable">
        <li class="droppable"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
        <li class="droppable"><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
            <ul class=" sortable2 connectedSortable">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="droppable"><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
        <li class="droppable"><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a>
            <ul class=" sortable2 connectedSortable">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu Item 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="droppable"><a href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>​
```

The functionality I want to have is when I drag an item out of the sub-menu, the sub-menu will hide and when I drag it into an `li` which has a sub-menu, it will open.

```
$(".droppable").hover(
    function () {
        $("ul", this).slideDown(100);
    },
    function () {
        $("ul", this).slideUp(100);
    }
).droppable({

    tolerance: 'intersect',
    over: function(event, ui) {
        if($(ui.draggable).parent() !== $(this)){
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
        }

        $("ul", this).slideDown(100);
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        if($(ui.draggable).parent() !== $(this)){
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
        }

        $("ul", this).slideUp(100);
    }
});​
```

The problem is that when I use jQuery UI sortable `over:` method, when I hover over the `li` with the sub-menu, the sub menu is open, however, when I move the item into the `ul`, it closes, since the moving out of the top `li` triggers the `out:` method which I set to close the menu.

How can I keep the `ul` open after I move the draggable outside it's parent `li`?

http://jsfiddle.net/6pgHa/6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".sortable1, .sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    placeholder: "sortable-nav-items-placeholder"
}).disableSelection();

var dontClose = false;
$(".droppable").hover(
    function () {
        $("ul", this).slideDown(100);
    },
    function () {        
        $("ul", this).slideUp(100);
    }
).droppable({

    tolerance: 'intersect',
    activate: function(event, ui) {
        dontClose = !!(ui.draggable[0]);        
    },
    over: function(event, ui) {
        if($(ui.draggable).parent() !== $(this)){
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
        }

        $("ul", this).slideDown(100);
    },
    out: function(event, ui) {
        if(dontClose) return;
        if($(ui.draggable).parent() !== $(this)){
            $(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
        }

        $("ul", this).slideUp(100);
    },
    drop : function(event, ui) {
        dontClose = false;        
    }
});​
```

OK I've modified them with some boolean flag.
Don't have time to test now but it should give you at least directions to experiment.
If any questions feel free to ask I'll look at it some hours later
Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6pgHa/18/

Comment: thanx, but the drop-lists don't close at all when you drag our now. BTW why do you use `!!`?

Comment: In javascript there are truthy and falsy statements. So in that case if the the DOM li element exists double negative will turn it to true.
OK noted, I'll check it out later when I have time and will solve it somehow

Comment: why not just `dontClose = ui.draggable[0];`